# trying to set an image as button image after picking the image from uiimagepicker

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode5

i have tried to get an answer to this question for a while. what i am trying to do is fire the `UIImagePickerController` and either choose from camera or select from goto library. this part works just fine. then i want to set that image as the button image on top of the button i am using to fire the image picker. in iOS 6 that was working just fine. since iOS 7 the image does not get set as the button image. i have tried many links and read many posts and went through even dev forum with no success in finding an answer. this is the last part of my desperate attempt to find an answer before going to apple technical support. i am hoping someone would be able to help me out. below is the code i am using to set the image to the button after selecting it from `UIImagePickerController`.

```
- (IBAction)choosePhoto
{
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (IBAction)takePhoto {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
 if (imagePicker) {
    self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self.choosePhotoButton setImage:self.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 } else {

    if (picker) {
        self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
     [self.takePhotoButton setImage:self.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
 }

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
imagePicker = nil;
}
```

currently after selecting either button the image set on it is the tint color of the button as it shows in the screen shot below. the two white squares are the buttons where the picked image should be.

[image: Screen Shot]

can someone take a look at my code and help me solve this issue?

Comment: anyone cares to contribute?

Comment: "the image set on it is the tint color of the button as it shows in the screen shot below"... all I can see is white... where is the tint thing and can you share/show before and after effects of selecting an image on screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the document called "Buttons" that's referenced in the UIButton Class Reference. When you add an image to a button (System type), it's added to the left of the title and as a template image, unless you set the rendering mode of the image to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal. So, if you want the image to the left, you can do this:

```
- (IBAction)setImageForSender:(id)sender {
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.jpg"];
    buttonImage = [buttonImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    [sender setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

If you want the image under the title (and centered in the button) set the background image instead. This shows up normally, you don't have to deal with the rendering mode.

```
- (IBAction)setImageForSender:(id)sender {
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.jpg"];
        [sender setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Here is the relevant portion of that "Buttons" document:

> Images
>
> Using the Image (currentImage) field, you can specify an image to
>   appear within the content of your button. If the button has a title,
>   this image appears to the left of it, and centered otherwise. The
>   image does not stretch or condense, so make sure to select an image
>   that is the proper size to appear in your button. Note that this image
>   will be automatically rendered as a template image within the button,
>   unless you explicitly set its rendering mode to
>   UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal. For more information, see Template
>   Images.
>
> The Background (currentBackgroundImage) field allows you to specify an
>   image to appear behind button content and fill the entire frame of the
>   button. The image you specify will stretch to fill the button if it is
>   too small. It will be cropped if it is too large.

That the last piece of information in the text above about the image being cropped if it's too large, only happens if you set a specific size for your button. If its size is determined by its intrinsic content size (that's the default if you just drag out a button in IB and don't give it size constraints), it will expand to the size of the image.

Comment: You were absolutely right and also a life saver. I can't believe I didn't see it. Thank you, thank you, thank you for saving my sanity. I accepted your answer and up voted it.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey, yeah, I just found out about this when I tried to answer your question. I haven't caught up yet with all the iOS 7 changes, of which there are many.